# how to get value from edittext which is placed into custom listview

Tags: android, listview

i have a custom listview and for every row their is one Edit text and one Button.
I just want to get value of edit text when we click on that button.

[click here for activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp40V.png)

as shown in image i want to get value of edittext which is for quantity when we click on add to cart Button.
For that i used Adapter and code was like below:

```
public class ProductList_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
int resource;
List<ProductList_ModelClass> productList_modelClasses = new ArrayList<>();

TextView tv_product_title;
TextView tv_product_price;
ImageView img_productImage;
RatingBar rb_custom_productlist;
EditText et_productQty;
Button btn_addto_Cart;
String product_Qty;

public ProductList_Adapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.productList_modelClasses = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.productList_modelClasses.size();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }

    img_productImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_productImage);
    tv_product_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_title);
    tv_product_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
    rb_custom_productlist = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_custom_productlist);
    et_productQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_productQty);
    btn_addto_Cart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_addto_Cart);


    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_image())
            .resize(250, 250)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.icon_placeholder)   // optional
            .error(R.mipmap.icon_error)      // optional
            .into(img_productImage);

    tv_product_title.setText(productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_name());
    rb_custom_productlist.setRating(productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_rating());
    tv_product_price.setText("₹ " + productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_price());


    product_Qty = et_productQty.getText().toString();

    btn_addto_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, product_Qty + , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("product_id", productList_modelClasses.get(position).getProduct_id());
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Get each EditTexts values of ListView with custom ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953066/android-get-each-edittexts-values-of-listview-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 1):

Another practice is to use the ViewHolder pattern. 
In the clickListener of the `holder.btn_addto_Cart`, you can get data from that edittext and do the processing.

```
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_product_title;
    TextView tv_product_price;
    ImageView img_productImage;
    RatingBar rb_custom_productlist;
    EditText et_productQty;
    Button btn_addto_Cart;
    String product_Qty;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resouce, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.img_productImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_productImage);
        holder.tv_product_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_product_title);
        holder.tv_product_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
        holder.rb_custom_productlist = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rb_custom_productlist);
        holder.et_productQty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_productQty);
        holder.btn_addto_Cart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addto_Cart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.btn_addto_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, holder.et_productQty.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Lists`, `Recyclerviews`, etc. for displaying data ), hold all your edittext's values in models that are connected to your list with adapter.

for example if you edit some `edittext` in position 5 then save this edit value when it's changed immediately in list model connected to your view with adapter in position 4 (0 is first). Or you can save it to model when you end edit, but in anyway save to model. Don't keep your data in `views` it's bad practice ) For example recyclerview reuses views so your will simple loose your data when you scroll )